# How to create translucent effect in visual basic windows forms?

Tags: vb.net, forms, macos

Like the image below:

![The transparency effect i mean ][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ststz.jpg

That effect in vb.You can actually see the background but its not purely transparent .Its translucent afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you some ideas: 
You can set the BackColor and TransparencyKey Color properties of your form to the same color.
Then assign the transparent image that you want, through handling the Mybase.Paint event, in this way:

```
   Private Sub frmLogin_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, 
         ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint

        If Not Me.cObjImagen Is Nothing Then
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.cObjImagen, 0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Where 'cObjImagen' is a system.drawing.Image loaded from 'form_load' event, or from ' public sub new() ', for example...

If you need to move the form, this will help you to process the messages correctly:

```
 Private Const WM_NCHITTEST As Integer = 132
    Private Const HTCAPTION As Integer = 2
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_NCHITTEST Then
            m.Result = New IntPtr(HTCAPTION)
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub
```